# GNU build object file

Tags: makefile, installation, automake, object-files

Is it possible to get the GNU build system to compile **and install** object files? I want to do this because I am using a commercial closed source code that supports user-created features that are linked in via object files.

The package I am building also creates a related library, but I would like to "install" two specific object files (e.g. file1.o and file2.o).

My current Makefile.am file is:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylib.la

libmylib_la_SOURCES = \
                        det3x3.f90 \
                        octree.cpp \
                        octree.h \
                        point.h
```

When I "make install" I get a clean directory with lib/ -- but I would also like to also get something like: obj/file1.o obj/file2.o. Is there something I can do to Makefile.am (or any other file) to accomplish this?

Thank you for any help/tips/suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could show more of your makefile? The one you show doesn't have any targets.

Comment: It looks to me like you're using automake: this is an automake question, not a GNU make question.  You should add an automake tag and/or ask on the automake mailing list.

Comment: Thank you both. It's using automake -- I've corrected that in the tags.